# How to call ASP.NET MVC 3 method using HttpWebRequest and URL?

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

I'm trying to use a URL and HttpWebRequest object to call a MVC method in a .NET application running on a specific machine. I've searched around, but haven't been able to find anything that addresses this specific problem.

I have the machine's IP address and port number, as well as the method path. My URL looks like this:

```
http://{IPAddress}:{PortNumber}/Admin/Manager/MethodA
```

Method A is the method I'm trying to call. It's defined in a controller class:

```
[HttpGet]
public ActionResult MethodA()
{
  // Do stuff
  return Json("JSON result");
}
```

I've mapped the route:

```
"Admin/{controller}/{action}/{id}"
```

Let's say that the application with MethodA is running on Machine A. I want to remotely call MethodA from Machine B. Here's the code I'm running on MachineB:

```
string url = "http://{IPAddress}:{PortNumber}/Admin/Manager/MethodA";
HttpWebRequest request = (HttpWebRequest)HttpWebRequest.Create(url);
request.Method = "GET";
string responseText = String.Empty;
using (HttpWebResponse response = (HttpWebResponse)request.GetResponse())
{
  Stream dataStream = response.GetResponseStream();
  StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(dataStream);
  responseText = reader.ReadToEnd();
  reader.Close();
  dataStream.Close();
}
```

The call to HttpWebRequest.GetResponse() returns a 200 OK, but I can't find any evidence that Method A was actually called. I've added log statements and they aren't getting hit, so it looks like the call isn't even reaching the application. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: what do you get in responseText variable? And where it is declared?

Comment: Also, your `Stream` and `StreamReader` both need to be in `using` blocks.

Comment: just try pasting url http://{IPAddress}:{PortNumber}/Admin/Manager/MethodA in browser to check if its showing page not found 404 or giving some error.

Comment: You are returning some data in you response. Can you read that?

Comment: The only things you are doing "wrong" are that you're not disposing your streams properly and you're using the "old school" way of making HTTP requests rather than using `HttpClient`. Your `responseText` variable should contain the return value of `MethodA`.